# vb.net decimal column in datagridivew is not sorting numerically

Tags: vb.net, sorting, datagridview

I have a datagridview which is bounded to a table m_table constructed in my code. A column named price has decimal type.

```
DGV.DataSource = m_table
DGV.Columns(columnPrice).ValueType = System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal")
```

All prices are in decimal. But I found that when clicking the column header of DGV, the price column is sorted like a string. For example:

9.0, 13.5, 8->13.5, 8, 9.0

But I want sort numerically, that is
8,9.0,13.5

I wonder why decimal type cannot be sorted numerically. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set DataType of the column in bound DataTable?

If not, do so:

```
  m_table.Columns("columnPrice").DataType = GetType(Decimal)
```